# Raw socket listen not supported in winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock2

I am trying to listen to raw ICMP packets using winsock2. Everything works fine till binding, but it is failing on listen function

```c
#include <WS2tcpip.h> // it must be placed here
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32")

int _tmain(DWORD argc, LPTSTR* argv) {
    WSADATA wData;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_RAW;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_ICMP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_ALL;

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wData) != 0) {
        _tprintf(_T("WSAStartup() Failed: Reason %d\n"), WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    if (getaddrinfo(nullptr, "20000", &hints, &result) != 0) {
        _tprintf(_T("getaddrinfo() Failed: Reason: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET socServer = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (socServer == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        _tprintf(_T("socket() Failed: Reason: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        freeaddrinfo(result); result = nullptr;
        return 1;
    }

    if (bind(socServer, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen) != 0) {
        _tprintf(_T("bind() Failed: Reason: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        closesocket(socServer);
        freeaddrinfo(result); result = nullptr;
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result); result = nullptr;
    int optVal = 1;
    if (setsockopt(socServer, IPPROTO_RAW, SO_BROADCAST, (PCHAR)&optVal, sizeof(optVal)) == 0) {
        _tprintf(_T("setsockopt() Failed. Reason: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    if (listen(socServer, SOMAXCONN) != 0x0) {
        _tprintf(_T("listen() Failed: Reason: %d\n"), GetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        closesocket(socServer);
    }


    _getch();
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(socServer);
}
```

On executing this code, I am getting **listen() Failed: Reason: 10045**. This error means [**WSAEOPNOTSUPP**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2#wsaeopnotsupp) and desciption of the same says *Operation not supported.*

Comment: You can't use `listen()` with a `SOCK_RAW` socket, only with a `SOCK_STREAM` TCP socket. Why do you think you need to use `listen()` in this situation? You don't.

Comment: Yeah, that is right. But when I used `recvfrom` directly its get blocked no matter how many ping requests i send @RemyLebeau

Comment: `IPPROTO_RAW` is not a valid *level* for `setsockopt()` on Windows, and `SO_BROADCAST` is only valid for the `SOL_SOCKET` level. You are not detecting this mistake because your error handling on `setsocketopt()` is wrong. It returns `SOCKET_ERROR` (-1) on failure, not 0 as you are expecting. In any case, if you are trying to write a packet sniffer, this is not the right way to do it. Use `WSAIoctl(SIO_RCVALL)` instead of `setsockopt(IPPROTO_RAW, SO_BROADCAST)`. And you should be `bind()`'ing to port 0.